# unable to run .exe that consumes a dll file after changing dll name in the dll project properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am new to windows, I have a dll project that generates a dll and a test project which is an exe that consumes or calls the functions in dll. I am using visual studio 2010 to execute this. currently when i check the general properties of dll under configuration properties , the target name is DecryptEmailDll and target extension is .dll .With this the test exe runs fine and I get the desired output. But when i try to rename the dll's target name to TransformEmail, the build is fine ,but while running it says "unable to find DecryptEmailDll" . I am not able to understand why it is trying to find the old dll with the old name and not the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The test.exe has been built with the file name to search for. So you have to change it and rebuild it with the new dll name.

Comment: i haven't specified any filename. the exe just calls a function in that dll, thats it

Comment: Check the source and resources of the test.exe, it can't just call a function from ANY dll, it has to specify which one it wants to dynamically load.  
edit: A windows .exe may specify required dlls either directly in exe file information, so the dll is loaded by OS during loading the .exe itself (then the dll name has to be part of resources, or dependencies settings of the .exe project), or it can dynamically call one of loadLibrary functions, with filename of .dll, and then search for desired function by the name of function.

Comment: it is not dynamic loading. I have just included the .h of dll and called one of its function. nothing else

Comment: [About Dynamic-Link Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681914(v=vs.85).aspx) _"Dynamic linking allows a module to include only the information needed to locate an exported DLL function at load time or run time. Dynamic linking differs from the more familiar static linking, in which the linker copies a library function's code into each module that calls it."_ ... of course it is dynamically loaded (after the .exe is loaded by OS and the required dll-s list is extracted from it).

Comment: @AnushaHV: the VS may be hiding this mechanism from you so well, that in common cases you just add "dll" to your project, and the building script will make the .exe to have the dll name in the required dll table, so you don't worry about that. But if you will study how .exe works internally, you will see that it contains list of dlls to be loaded upon init time. And there are further win-api methods allowing you to load other dlls post-init dynamically from the code.

Comment: actually there was a .def file which had the functions of the dll, within that the dll name was still DecryptEmailDll which i then changed. This got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you change the name of the dll, you have to either change the import lib declaraction, if you static import the dll (I suppose with cahnge the dll name you meant also the name of the lib and exp). Or, if you dynamicly import, change the parameter of the LoadLibrary function.